# How do i prove how $S_5$ is generated by a two cycle and a five cycle?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

How do I prove that $S_5$ (the permutation group on five letters) can be generated by a two-cycle $(12)$ and a five cycle $(12345)$?

Comment: It's enough to show that you can produce every transposition.  That is, find a way to generate each of
$$
(13),(14),(15),(23),(24),(25),(34),(35),(45)
$$

Comment: @user146285 regarding that theorem for when $n$ is prime: $S_n$ is generated by $(12)$ and $(123\cdots n)$ for *all* $n$; the proof is very similar to what you see in the answers below. In the prime case, it is true that *any* two cycle together with *any* $n$-cycle generate $S_n$, because you can do a substitution to convert the $n$-cycle into one which, together with the given 2-cycle, "looks like" the above pair of generators. This can't necessarily be done if $n$ is composite, for example, $(1234)$ and $(13)$ do not generate $S_4$.

Comment: (My comment is in response to a deleted comment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define $s = (12345)$ and $t = (12)$.  Note that
$$
s\, t\, s^{-1} = (23)
$$
Similarly, 
$$
s^2 t s^{-2} = (34), \quad s^3 t s^{-3} = (45), \quad s^4 t s^{-4} = (51)
$$
From there, it's not too hard to get the rest of them.  For example, 
$$
(13) = (23)(12)(23)
$$
In this manner, we show that every transposition can be generated by $s$ and $t$.  Thus, all of $S_5$ is generated by $s$ and $t$.

[Lemma 2](http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/415conj.pdf) over here should help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

First, verfiy the following equalities:
\begin{align*}
(12345)(12)(12345)^{-1} &= (23)\\
(12345)^2(12)(12345)^{-2} &= (34)\\
(12345)^3(12)(12345)^{-3} &= (45).
\end{align*}
You can then use these three equalities to generate all transpositions, and hence all of $S_5$.

It actually turns out that this result can be generalized. Any symmetric group $S_n$ is generated by $(12)$ and $(1, 2, \dots, n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof that $S_{n}$ can be written as a product of transpositions:

Let $(1 2 3 ... n)\in S_{n}$ be a cycle of length n.

Now, $(1 2 3 ... n-1 n)=(1 n)(1 (n-1))...(1 4)(1 3)(1 2)$

For example, $(7 6 3)$ can be written as $(7 3)(7 6)$

$(1 2 3 4 5)\in S_{5}$. Then $(1 2 3 4 5)=(1 5)(1 4)(1 3)(1 2)$